# Frameset not remove in IE browser

Tags: html, css

This Html code was converted from excel file then I just save it to a webpage format. Then, since in excel file there are sheets at the bottom part so when I convert it into html file, slides or sheets can still be seen in the webpage. Something like this.

IE browser:

[image]

Chrome Browser:

[image]

When I delete this following code in the html.

```
<frame src="Proposal%20format%20of%20Craftmanship_new_revision_files/tabstrip.htm" name="frTabs" marginwidth=0 marginheight=0>
```

It works perfectly fine in Chrome, however, in IE browser the frame or slides is still visible. I need to remove this one in IE since this is our default browser and this application should be open in this browser.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `frameborder`, `border` and `framespacing` attributes of the `frameset` tag to control how the frames are rendered, for example:

```
<frameset frameborder="0" border="0" framespacing="0">
    <frame ...>
```

Comment: I have this following codes already.. `<frameset rows="*,39" border=0 width=0 frameborder=no framespacing=0>`

Comment: You can also use the `frameborder="0"` attribute on the `frame` tag.